# Show No data message when chart has no data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, charts

I am trying to show no data message when chart has no data.
Is it correct?

```
  var ctx = document.getElementById('mycanvas').getContext('2d');
        var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                labels: ["aa", "bb", "cc", "dd"],
                datasets: [{
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    backgroundColor: ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yello'],
                    data: data.length ? data: [{ label: "No Data", value: 100 }],
                }]
            },
            options: {
                legend: {
                    position: 'right',
                    labels: {
                        boxWidth: 12
                    }
                },
                tooltips: { bodyFontSize: 12 }
            }
        });
```

I am not getting No data message when data length is 0.

Comment: Your ternary seems to be false

Comment: return `data.length` and check the result, if it return `0` try `data.length <= 0` but i think this way goes nothing..

Comment: What I can advice to you is manage it in the view. Don't display chart at all if there isn't data.

`<canvas id="mycanvas" ng-if="data.length > 0"></canvas>` & `<span ng-if="data.length == 0">No data</span>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest is to use conditional rendering.

Assuming you're using AngularJS (you referenced tag), you can use `ngIf` directive. If data array is empty, then don't display chart.

```
<canvas id="myChart" ng-if="data != 0"></canvas>
<span ng-if="data == 0">No data</span>
```

Else, you can solve it in your script, by checking before or after draw the data length. I recommend you [this snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/x04ptfuu/).

Other solution following your wish could be to adapt drawn data to received data.

```
    if($scope.requestedLeaveTypeCount.length > 0){
      data = {
        labels: ["EL", "AL", "PL", "CL"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: ['#F0CB8C', '#A9D5D4', '#E8A3D7', '#CFA3FD'],
            data: $scope.requestedLeaveTypeCount,
        }]
      }
    } else {
      data = {
        labels: ["No data"],
        datasets: [{
          labels:'No data',
          backgroundColor: ['#D3D3D3'],
          data: [100]
        }]
      }
    }
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/QXljAeeM4Ul3Y47EPcbq?p=preview

Comment: whats wrong here `data: data!= 0? data: [{ label: "No Data", value: 100 }]`

Comment: I will get 0 in `data`.

Comment: @krish there's not a well written ternary. `(condition) ? ok : not_ok`

If you get 0 in data, see my updated answer

Comment: sorry I couldn't get you.  `data: (data!= 0) ? data: [{ label: "No Data", value: 100 }]` Is this ok?

Comment: Nop, you seem to be confused with ternaries. Ternary is like a `if/else`. `(condition) ? if : else`. Code you provide shows only `if` part, so your ternary becomes invalid.

Comment: `[{ label: "No Data", value: 100 }]` is this not else part in my code?

Comment: Oh ok sorry, I missunderstood some things.. I though you were trying to re-affect data value in your else part.

Comment: Did you try with ngIf or JS snippet I posted?

Comment: No ..Actually this method only I want.That is why.If you come to know any issue in my code.please let me know.

Comment: @krish please see my last edit on answer, with something similar to what you want

Comment: where is the no data message in you example?

Comment: @krish see it now? :)

Comment: Thank you so much Zooly.Lets edit all comments :-) ;-)

Comment: Js fiddle is working for me, Except font attribute. How to set font size with this code?