# Chart.js pie chart to display "No Data" if the datasets are empty

Tags: javascript, chart.js

If there is no data in the pie chart I am trying to display "no data to display". This works fine if the chart is a line, but if it is a pie chart, it is not working.  I have included the plugin for that but still I'm getting the desired output. Let me know where I'm doing mistakes

```js
Chart.plugins.register({
 afterDraw: function(chart) {
   if (chart.data.datasets.length === 0) {
     // No data is present
      var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;
      var width = chart.chart.width;
      var height = chart.chart.height
      chart.clear();
      
      ctx.save();
      ctx.textAlign = 'center';
      ctx.textBaseline = 'middle';
      ctx.font = "16px normal 'Helvetica Nueue'";
      ctx.fillText('No data to display', width / 2, height / 2);
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }
});

var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
 type: 'line',
  data: {
   labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'],
    datasets: []
  }
});

var ctx2 = document.getElementById('chart2').getContext('2d');
var myChart2 = new Chart(ctx2, {
 type:'pie',
  data:{
   labels:['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'],
    datasets:[{
     data:[],
      backgroundColor: ['red','blue','green','yellow']
    }]
  }
});

var ctx3 = document.getElementById('chart3').getContext('2d');
var myChart3 = new Chart(ctx3, {
 type: 'pie',
  data: {
   labels: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'],
    datasets: []
  }
});
```

```html
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
<canvas id="chart2"></canvas>
<canvas id="chart3"></canvas>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You could always adds a check for the current chart type (`chart.config.type`) in your plugin; and then based on the current chart type make the necessary changes in howto validate an empty datasets. Based on your example, an empty pie chart datasets would be `chart.data.datasets[0].data.length === 0`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47750288/show-no-data-message-when-chart-has-no-data

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show No data message when chart has no data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47750288/show-no-data-message-when-chart-has-no-data)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var ctx2 = document.getElementById('chart2').getContext('2d');
var myChart2 = new Chart(ctx2, {
    type:'pie',
    data:{
      labels:['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr'],
      datasets:[]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did in my angular application is duplicate my doughnut chart.

Give the placeholder one `position: absolute; z-index: 1;` via a css class `.placeholder-chart`

```
.real-chart {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}

.placeholder-chart {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Then I initialize my chart data as 100% and background color as desired:

```
options: {
    "aspectRatio": 1.75,
    "legend": {
        "display": false,
    },
    "title": {
        "display": false,
    },
    "rotation": - Math.PI,
    "circumference": Math.PI
}

realData: {
    // My real data, which result 0 in this case
}

placeholderData: {
    "labels": "",
    "datasets": [
        {
           "label": [""],
           "data": [100],
           "backgroundColor": "#F2EEE8"
        }
    ]
}
```

My template:

```
<chart
    class="placeholder-chart"                                
    [type]="'doughnut'"
    [data]="placeholderData"
    [options]="options"></chart>
<chart
    class="real-chart"
    [type]="'doughnut'"
    [data]="realData"
    [options]="options"></chart>
```

In picture 1 I only get a thin yellow zero line

[image]

In picture 2 I have the 2 charts - the placeholder one above the real one

[image]

In picture 3 then the overlapped two charts

[image]